# Using Bootstrap Navbar in React.js

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am new to React and I want some of menu's to Dropdown when I click on it. But I am stuck with making everything look like it should be but cannot find the answer to make it actually work.

I attached following link into my html folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

My Component folder looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">holidaylettings</a>
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul className="ml-auto navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">My shortlist <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item currency">
              <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownCurrencyLink" data-toggle="currency" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">GBP</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">Manage my booking</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item help">
              <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownHelpLink" data-toggle="help" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item entry">
              <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownEntryLink" data-toggle="entry" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sign in</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                List your property
              </a>
              <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownCurrencyLink">
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">GBP</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">USD</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">CHF</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">EUR</a>
              </div>

              <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownHelpLink">
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Travellers</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Manage existing bookings</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Common questions</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Owners</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Common question</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Search</a>
              </div>

              <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownEntryLink">
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Travellers</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Owners/Managers</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Nav;
```

Everything looks okay, but when I click on the menu, I want it to show what is supposed to show eg: different currencies

I do not know how to do that.

I would like to NOT install bootstraps and prefer use plain Bootstrap rather than Ract one if possible

Comment: Problem is not react-bootstrap but regular bootstrap applies changes to DOM without React knowledge, so if data changes, all changes made by bootstrap are reverted. It is possible to avoid it, but on every update you have to again initialize bootstrap. react-bootstrap would be less painful soulution. You write eg. <Nav><NavItem>... so you write less code and you don't care about mentioned problems.

Comment: Okay. So can I use react-bootstrap without installing it? I have read about it, that I need to paste the code into my folders but don't know if it will be enough to start using react-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In as much as you would like to use the bootstrap that depends on Jquery, in order to enjoy the best of React, It is recommended that you use the bootstrap variation that work best with ReactJs(ReactStrap or React Bootstrap). It is simple and easier to follow.

To try or adopt reactstrap, you may visit https://reactstrap.github.io/ or https://react-bootstrap.github.io/ so as to get familiar with reactstrap and then follow its documentation.

It might be helpful, all the best.